# How can I prove that the following poisson process is not continuous on any interval?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, poisson-process

> Let $(N^{(n)})_{n\in \Bbb{Z}}$ be a sequence of i.i.d. Poisson processes. Then define $Y_t=\sum_{n=0}^\infty 4^{-n} N^{(n)}_{3^nt}$ I want to show that almost surely for all intervals $(u,v)\subset [0,\infty)$, $Y:=(Y_t)_{t\geq 0}$ is not continuous.

I could prove that if we fix $t$ then $Y$ is continuous at $t$. But not I need to show that on every interval it is not.

But unfortunately I have no idea how to construct a situation on $(u,v)$ which tells me that it is not continuous there.

Can someone help me further?

Comment: Just to check: $k$ here denotes a positive real, not an integer?

Comment: @NateEldredge right, maybe I will swap it to $t$

Comment: @NateEldredge can you help me how to solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: For each $(u,v)$, $Y_t$ would be continuous on $(u,v)$ if and only if none of the Poisson processes $N^{(n)}_{3^n t}$ had a jump in that interval.  For each $n$, compute the probability of the event that $N^{(n)}_{3^n t}$ has a jump in $(u,v)$.  Then use independence to show the probability that at least one such event happens is 1.  The second Borel-Cantelli lemma could help (you could show the stronger statement that almost surely, infinitely many such events happen).

We are not quite done yet: we have that for each $(u,v)$ the process is a.s. not continuous on $(u,v)$, but the null set where this fails could depend on the interval $(u,v)$.  We want to show that almost surely, the process is continuous on no $(u,v)$; that is, we want a single null set that works for all $(u,v)$.  To get this, note that it suffices to show that a.s, the process is continuous on no *rational* interval $(u,v)$, and that there are only countably many such intervals.

Comment: wouldn't it be $Y_t$ continuous on $(u,v)$ iff $N^{(n)}_{3^nt}$ has no jump?

Comment: @Summerday: Yes, I believe that's the same as what I said: if *none* of the $N^{(n)}_{3^nt}$, $n=1,2,3,\dots$, has a jump.

Comment: ah sorry I haven't read the none.

Can you give me a hint how to compute the probability that it has a jump?

Comment: @Summerday: The number of jumps made by a Poisson process during a given time interval has a Poisson distribution (hence the name), with a parameter $\lambda$ that you should know.  Using this you can find the probability that the number of jumps is at least 1.  (You can save yourself having to deal with an infinite sum by finding the probability that the number of jumps is 0, and subtracting from 1.)

Comment: No I don't know that the jumps are poisson distributed

Comment: @Summerday: What is your book's definition of a Poisson process, then?  And what other facts about Poisson processes have you already established?  Usually this fact is part of the definition, or is one of the very first things that one proves.

Comment: It is a continuous time process $N:=(N_t)_{t\geq 0}$ with values in $\Bbb{N}\cup\{\infty\}$ satisfying the following properties: $N_0=0$ a.s., $N_t\sim \operatorname{Poi}(t)$ for all $t>0$, $N$ has independent and stationary increments, $t\mapsto N_t$ is right continuous and non decreasing

Comment: @Summerday: Okay, so, stationary Poisson increments.  The number of jumps made by $N_t$ in the interval $(u,v)$ is $N_v - N_u \sim \mathrm{Poi}(v-u)$; this is what I meant by my earlier comment.  With the time rescaling, the number of jumps made by $N_{3^n t}$ in $(u,v)$ is $N_{3^n v} - N_{3^n u} \sim \mathrm{Poi}(3^n(v-u))$.  Now, what's the probability for such a random variable to equal 0?

Comment: the probability is $e^{-3^n(v-u)}$ right?

Comment: @Summerday: Right.